# How can I call the Id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I've made a javascript function that produces a popup window but the popup is dependent with an id on another form so I was wondering this could be done. Here's what I've done so far:

```
$('.popupWindow').click(function () {
  var model = { NameId: $('#NameId').val()}
  myWindow = window.open('/Company/Edit/0?NameId=' + model, '',     
    'scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500')
  myWindow.focus()
});
```

This already create a popup window but the Id it gets returns object Object so the url for the popup screen becomes `~/Company/Edit/0?NameId=[object Object]` so obviously, it returns an error. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using MVC 3 by the way. And I'm also using ActionLink (razr) for the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a model with a property `NameId`, so instead of using model use this:

```
model.NameId
```

In your example it will look like this:

```
myWindow = window.open('/Company/Edit/0?NameId=' + model.NameId, '',   'scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of

```
NameId: $('#NameId').val()
```

this

```
NameId: $('#NameId').attr('id');
```